# Wildfly failed to start service: NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/diagnostics/debug/DebugLogger

Tags: java, weblogic, wildfly

I am migrating my code which was previously using weblogic, to using wildfly app server. However, it seems like I am missing a class file "weblogic/diagnostics/debug/DebugLogger" and thus the wildfly server failed to start. I couldn't find this library anywhere. I am new to wildfly and weblogic, just trying to get project to be able to deploy, how can I possibly resolve this error?? Thanks a lot.

PS. Unable to provide error log

Comment: Your application is using a weblogic feature which will not be available with wildfly. You have to review your code to replace or remove this feature.

Comment: As stated by @EmmanuelCollin you have to change the code of your application to remove the dependency of `weblogic/diagnostics/debug/DebugLogger` which is WebLogic server specific class.